# How to measure chunk inhabited time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Mob spawning is affected by [Local difficulty](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Regional_difficulty), which considers time inhabited in a chunk.

How can I measure the time inhabited in a chunk? According to the [chunk format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format) it is stored in NBT data for each chunk, but I want to know if there's a way to check (possibly with external tools) that does not involve an NBT editor.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking - in-game the time inhabited is right after the local difficulty in the F3 screen (highly visible on the page you linked). External tools would have to work on the save file directly but they still need to be able to read NBT to do that - they may not be NBT editors but they'll be NBT viewers at least. Can you elaborate what is final goal you are after?

Comment: @Kcats nope that is total daytime. I am asking about the value known as InhabitedTime.